# file.nb from Mathematica has a strange format on GitHub

Tags: github, wolfram-mathematica

I want to download a file with the extension .nb that was uploaded to a GitHub repository. However, it has a strange format that I can't get round and use it like the original. Here is a sample of what it looks like:

```
(*** Wolfram Notebook File ***)
(* http://www.wolfram.com/nb *)

(* CreatedBy='Mathematica 7.0' *)

(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       145,          7]
NotebookDataLength[   1053158,      18799]
NotebookOptionsPosition[   1043705,      18664]
NotebookOutlinePosition[   1044264,      18683]
CellTagsIndexPosition[   1044221,      18680]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"(*", 
  RowBox[{"Import", " ", "data", " ", "from", " ", 
   RowBox[{"the", " ", ".", "csv"}]}], "*)"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8325121403603525\`*^9, 3.832512162342577*^9}, 
   3.8338276384526296`*^9},
 FontFamily->"Consolas",
 FontWeight->"Normal",ExpressionUUID->"6e20bfb1-78fc-454a-85f3-fab3e1e1f609"],

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"s", "=", 
   RowBox[{
   "Import", "[", "\"\<C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\Desktop\\\\data02.csv\>\"", 
    "]"}]}], ";"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.831030550939706*^9, 3.831030563133726*^9}, {
   3.83103080712603*^9, 3.8310308583911963\`*^9}, {3.8310332771328163\`*^9, 
   3.831033277194804*^9}, {3.8310363192249303\`*^9, 3.831036327345213*^9}, {
   3.83330485714029*^9, 3.8333048619195776\`*^9}, 3.833829927653514*^9, {
   3.833833840478625*^9, 3.833833846148329*^9}},
 FontFamily->"Consolas",
 FontWeight->"Bold",ExpressionUUID->"4af89285-72de-4b68-b0f1-ffa673886bec"],

(...)
```

I have looked into the link that is present in this sample, but couldn't find anything useful.

What should I do to recover its initial state. In other words, what can be done to reuse the functions and content that it had?

Comment: @Bill Thank you for replying. Yes, I do have a licensed copy of Mathematica. Here is the file in the given repository https://github.com/LouXonline/Mag-AZ/blob/main/multipole.nb . I have tried saving and opening this file on Mathematica, but it still isn't formatted the right way. I appreciate your help, but I feel that rewriting the file's content would not be worth it. For context, it is a file in which I have worked before, but the only way I can work on it again is by importing from this repository.

Comment: @Bill I am the author of the file. It just happens that right now I don't have access to the original file. Using the data in the repository would be the easiest way. I will assume that there is no easy path to recover Mathematica's common language from that file. But either way, thank you for trying to help. 

Edit - just realised you commented two times

Comment: I am sorry that I did not understand what you had or what you were trying to do. Perhaps this? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/StandardForm.html Or perhaps posting on https://community.wolfram.com/ and saying that you have a very old version 7 notebook file on github.com/LouXonline/Mag-AZ/blob/main/multipole.nb and you want to recover the original expression form for all of that and simply and easily convert that entire notebook to back to InputForm. Or perhaps the word "InputForm" is not what you are asking for. Finding some way the reader will really understand your need.

Comment: @Bill There is no problem. I will eventually find a way to put the notebook into InputForm, starting at your suggestions. I believe you got the term of what I wanted right. Again, thank you for trying. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the normal underlying code of a Mathematica notebook. If you copy the code into a plain text editor and save it with the extension .nb it should open normally in Mathematica.

Comment: Can't believe I did not try the simplest thing.